# how to update value of dataclass python

Tags: python-3.x

I have following function `update_value` in section I that should return a dictionary if some keys are matched then update the key's value
or if rate is provided then update all key's value. I also need to setup  key's type. after searching, it seems like I
should create my own dataclass and I have code like in section II. but if there is better way for me to do it?

```
#section I
def update_value(**kwargs):
    default = dict(a=0.1, b=0.2, c=0.3)
    if kwargs.get('rate'):
        return {k: v * kwargs['rate'] for k, v in default.items()}
    default.update(**kwargs)
    return default

#section II
from dataclasses import dataclass, field, fields
@dataclass
class TestValue:
    """
    This describes how to map default bidding value for advance bid value
    """
    a: float = field(default=0.1)
    b: float = field(default=0.5)
    c: float = field(default=25.0)

    def update(self, rate):
        for field in fields(self):
            setattr(self, field.name, getattr(self, field.name) * rate)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    v_I = update_value(a=8)  # v = {'a': 8, 'b': 0.2, 'c': 0.3}
    v_I = update_value(a=8, b=18)  # v = {'a': 8, 'b': 18, 'c': 0.3}
    v_I = update_value(rate=10)  # v = {'a': 1.0, 'b': 2.0, 'c': 3.0}
    def func(v: TestValue, **kwargs):
        return v(**kwargs)
    v_II = TestValue()
    v_II.update(10) # v_I = {'a': 1.0, 'b': 2.0, 'c': 3.0}
    func(v_II, a=8, b=18)# v_I = {'a': 8, 'b': 18, 'c': 0.3}
```